# Why my error is not being handled in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, error-handling

I am learning express.js, and I am thinking why I receive UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and no error response is being sent after executing http api call..

For error handling I have created helper class and middleware:

```
/helpers/errorHander.js
------------------------------------
class ErrorHandler extends Error {
  constructor(statusCode, message) {
    super();
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

const handleError = (err, res) => {
  const { statusCode, message } = err;
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    status: 'error',
    statusCode,
    message
  });
};

module.exports = {
  ErrorHandler,
  handleError
};
```

I have enabled this middleware in app.js file:

```
/app.js
------------------------------------
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const config = require('./config/init');
const cors = require('cors');
const { handleError, ErrorHandler } = require('./helpers/errorHandler');

//routes
const apiRoutes = require('./api');

// connect db
config.initializeDB();

// configure bodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Enable Cors
app.use(cors());

// Set Routes
app.use('/', apiRoutes);

app.get('/error', (req, res) => {
  throw new ErrorHandler(500, 'Internal server error');
});

// Enable error handling middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  handleError(err, res);
});

module.exports = app;
```

When I perform request to the /error endpoint, it works correctly:
[/error endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Prg.png)
But when performing request to the endpoint which performs operations with mongoose I am not getting desired result:
[/v1/users/ endpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR1Rk.png)

user.route.js:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const userController = require('./user.controller');

router.get('/', userController.getUsers);
router.post('/', userController.createUser);

module.exports = router;
```

user.controller.js:

```
const userService = require('../../../services/user');

module.exports = {
  getUsers: (req, res, next) => {
    return res.json(userService.getUsers());
  },
  createUser: (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    res.json(userService.createUser(username, password));
  }
};
```

user.service.js:

```
const User = require('../models/user');
const { ErrorHandler } = require('../helpers/errorHandler');

module.exports = {
  getUsers: async () => {
    return User.find({});
  },
  createUser: async (username, password) => {
    const user = new User({ username, password });
    try {
      await user.save();
      return user;
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code === 11000) {
        throw new ErrorHandler(409, 'Username already exists!');
      }
      throw new ErrorHandler(500, 'Internal server error');
    }
  }
};
```

Console gives such a warning:
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snreC.png)

Why it is not working as I want, and how can I make it work?

=========================================================
Update #1
As user - jfriend00 suggested, I tried to await the promise, and here my code looks like on user.controller.js:

```
const userService = require('../../../services/user');

module.exports = {
  getUsers: (req, res, next) => {
    return res.json(userService.getUsers());
  },
  createUser: async (req, res, next) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;
    try {
      let user = await userService.createUser(username, password);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
  }
};
```

And Now I get the desired outcome.

Comment: In `user.service.js`, your `createUser()` function is `async`.  That means when you `throw` in it, it will return a rejected promise.  But, in `user.controller.js` where you call `userService.createUser()`, it's done like this:  `res.json(userService.createUser(username, password));` which will not ever work because `userService.createUser()` returns a promise that will eventually resolve or reject.  It doesn't return a value directly.  You will need to `let result = await userService.createUser()` and make sure you handle a possible rejected promise there too.

Comment: Thanks! I have updated post, it now works when awaiting the createUser method and then passing error object to next() middleware. Maybe you have some suggestions how could I even make it better the codebase?

Comment: FYI, here on stackoverflow, questions remain questions.  Answers go in answers, not in your question.  So, you can post your solution in an answer and after some time has passed, you can even "accept" it by selecting the checkmark to the left of it to indicate to the community that your question has been answered.

Comment: So, this `res.json(userService.createUser(username, password));` still isn't right.